# How do you convert a jruby-based application to ruby?

Tags: ruby, jruby

I made an application using jruby but I want to get it to work on a different computer which only has ruby installed.
It won't let me just change the gemfile from jruby to ruby, so how can I change it to run based on ruby?

This is my gemfile using jruby:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.2.2', :engine => 'jruby', :engine_version => '9.0.0.0'

gem 'cowsay'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter'
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :jruby]

gem 'puma'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
ruby '2.2.2', :engine => 'jruby', :engine_version => '9.0.0.0'
```

to:

```
ruby '2.2.2'
```

and change:

```
gem 'activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter'
```

to:

```
gem 'pg'
```

You probably need to update you database.yml also.  You didn't paste it here, so I can't be sure.  Just lookup the pg gem to see what you need to configure your conetions to.

Answer (score 0):

no need to actually change much stuff as suggested in the other answer.
in the *Gemfile* specify platform qualifiers for MRI/JRuby specific gems :

```
# ruby '2.2.2', :engine => 'jruby', :engine_version => '9.0.0.0'
# ...
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
# ...
gem 'activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter', platform: :jruby
gem 'pg', platform: :mri
```

if you're not using anything AR-JDBC specific in *database.yml* (e.g. `url: jdbc:postrgresql:...`) than the same configuration with work on JRuby as well as C-Ruby